# Java upgrade problem on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, java

I want to upgrade my `jdk` on a `CentOS` server, after some simple searches I found some solutions.

From [this link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), you can see that the instructions are simple.

- install your chosen jdk from rpm package or from source
- possibly choose some alternatives
- check that the new version installed (`java -version`)

The first two steps above, I easily completed, but in check version step I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I have also checked:

```
alternatives --config java
```

and symbolic links.

I have also tried `which` command to find out what java is actually running and this was the link directions.

```
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/jdk-1.8.0_40/bin/java
```

the weird thing is that when I run:

```
/usr/bin/java -version
```

It is OK and it returns the version but when I run `java` without any prefix I got that error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a system variable `CLASSPATH`.

and it must be exported in some way for example `/etc/bashrc` file because jdk needs to know the pass of classes and libraries to load it's modules.

in my case i sat `CLASSPATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/lib`.